# When typing can you change what the text is displayed as?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i am making a program to test a password and was wondering, When the user enters their password can you stop their password from showing as they type it in to the console/GUI?

Comment: For a console application, it's best to use the getpass module even though it doesn't change the typed characters into asterisks.

Comment: Are you sure you want `*` to be echoed? Would having the display of the keypresses suppressed suffice?

Comment: Yeah suppressing the keypresses would work but How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has you covered with a built-in library:

```
>>> import getpass
>>> pw = getpass.getpass()
```

Edit: As mentioned by @MattH, this won't echo asterisks (*) while user types the password.

Comment: Doesn't provide `*` for keypresses

Answer (score 1):

```
import tkinter as tk 

root = tk.Tk()

def store():
    pw = my_box.get()

my_box = tk.Entry(root, show='*')
my_box.pack()
Button(text='Submit', command=store).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This will work in a GUI. You can then call `pw = my_box.get()` where necessary.

---

You can *hide* user `input` in the console using the [`getpass`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/getpass.html) module- but this only hides and does not display asterisks.

```
>>> import getpass
>>> pw = getpass.getpass()
```

But displaying asterisks in the console is a little more complicated; you would need to use `sys` and `msvcrt`- Google it or ask a separate question asking how to use these modules for that purpose; I don't know.